# How do I get Launchpad to see apps on an external disk?

Tags: macos, external-disk, launchpad

I have a large Firewire disk permanently plugged into my Mac mini.  Whenever possible, this external disk is where I install any new apps.  How do I get these apps to show up in Launchpad?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured this out.  All I had to do was drag the folder containing the apps to the Launchpad icon on the dock.